# NameError: [Class] not defined

Tags: python, django, apache

I intend to create a many-to-one relationship between these two classes:

```
class Bonds(models.Model):
    types = models.ForeignKey(Types)
    rowid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    bond_id = models.TextField(blank=True)
    end_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    intr = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    base_i = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_d = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_id = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_pd = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'bonds'
        in_db = 'bonds'

class Types(models.Model):
    rowid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    cal = models.TextField(blank=True) # This field type is a guess.
    ind = models.TextField(blank=True)
    paypy = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loan_type = models.TextField(blank=True)
    adj_intr_date = models.NullBooleanField()
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'types'
        in_db = 'bonds'
```

I am running Django inside Apache2. When I try to run this code, an error occurs:

```
NameError at /: name 'Types' is not defined
```

Is this not the correct way to define a ForeignKey relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is standard in Python that names need to be defined before you can use them. In your case, the `Types` class is not defined until after the declaration of the `types` field that references it. You could fix this by swapping the order of the classes, or use a special workaround that Django enables: make the class reference a string:

```
types = models.ForeignKey('Types')
```

Comment: The workaround was precisely what I needed, thank you. I'm afraid switching the order of the classes would cause problems when importing foreign databases.

Comment: Sorry but now I get another error. OperationalError: no such column: bonds.types_id

Comment: So you added the foreign key, but did you migrate your database?

Comment: Yes, or I used syncdb as I have v1.6.

Comment: But that wasn't what I asked. syncdb doesn't change existing models, which is the whole point of having a separate migration tool and the move to integrate it in 1.7.

Comment: Oh, I see. Will South to the job?

Comment: South did indeed do the job. Thanks for your help sir.